# Website keeps reloading on mobile device - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, reload

on desktop, the site I made works perfectly, however on mobile, the page constantly refreshes not allowing the user to view any of the content. I was having difficulty making my site responsive, so I made a new file called mobile.html to show all of the content properly. When the screen is a certain size, the site redirects to the mobile.html. Here is the code I believe is producing the issue.

```js
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1500px, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      document.location = "mobile.html";
    }
  </script>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Appreciate any help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check `mobile.html` and make sure you don't have your forwarding code.

Alternatively you can check current page is not `mobile.html`.
You can use the code below this will put more control on your page.
First check if userAgent is mobile and then check if current page is not `mobile.html` if both true this means user is connecting from a mobile device but not viewing mobile page so forward to mobile page.

```js
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var mobilePage = 'mobile.html';

if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && filename !== mobilePage ) {
  document.location = mobilePage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.location == "example.com/mobile.html") {
    //do nothing
}

else if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    document.location = "mobile.html";
}
</script>
```